# Creating new columns from pandas.DataFrame.groupby(['arg1', 'arg2']) with mean values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have data similar to the following in a pandas.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year' : [2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002],
    'Month' : ['Aug', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Sep'],
    'Day' : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'Value' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  })
```

Now I group by 'Month' and 'Year', and calculate the mean value:

```
print(df.groupby(['Month', 'Year'])['Value'].mean())
```

The output looks like:

| Month | Year |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Aug | 2001 | 1.5 |
|  | 2002 | 5.5 |
| Sep | 2001 | 3.5 |
|  | 2002 | 7.5 |

Now I want to create a new data frame, that looks like this:

| Year | Aug | Sep |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | 1.5 | 3.5 |
| 2002 | 5.5 | 7.5 |

Are there any functions in the pandas module that could help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP is not far from the desired goal. As one is using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html), all one has to do is use [`pandas.DataFrame.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) as follows

```
df_new = df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Value'].mean().unstack()

[Out]:

Month  Aug  Sep
Year           
2001   1.5  3.5
2002   5.5  7.5
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked just the way I wanted and is very compact!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using pivot_table:

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Value', index=['Year'],
                columns=['Month'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Regards,
Jehona.

Comment: I guess, this is just the same (short version) as @abokey's answer

Comment: Yes, we're both using the same method, I didn't refresh the page to see there came an answer while I was also answering, the method pivot_table is the same while being the trivial in such a situation, however I let year as index as opposed to the previous answer.